# jquery text().replace('','') not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, appendtext

Hi I am trying for hours now to remove a text string again after I have appended it.

I have a script that handles an accordion and I have some redundancy in text in it. So I want to add and remove the redundant text on opening or closing the accordion row.

Here is my code:

```
var redundantText = "text text text <a href=\"#contact\">Contact Me</a> text text text";

$('#collapse_1').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(".dropdown_collapse_1").addClass("dropdown-indicator");
  $(".dropdown_collapse_1").removeClass("dropdown-collapsed");
  $("#redundant_text_wrapper").append(redundantText);
});
$('#collapse_1').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(".dropdown_collapse_1").addClass("dropdown-collapsed");
  $(".dropdown_collapse_1").removeClass("dropdown-indicator");
  $("#redundant_text_wrapper").text().replace(redundantText, '');
});
```

The append works fine but the text().replace() does not. So if I open and close the accordion row several times it always appends the redundantText but never removes it so that the redundantText gets even more redundant.

Edit:
changed 'redundantText' to redundantText. Still does not work

Edit2:

```
$("#redundant_text_wrapper").text($("#redundant_text_wrapper").text().replace(redundantText,''));
```

also does not help, it only removes the link but the text stays

Edit3:

```
$( "#redundant_text_wrapper").text(function(index, currentText) {
    return currentText.replace(redundantText,'');
});
```

also does only remove the link, text stays

Comment: change `$( "#redundant_text_wrapper").text().replace('redundantText',''); ` to: `$( "#redundant_text_wrapper").text().replace(redundantText,'');`

Comment: @SuperDJ Put it as an answer. :)

Comment: @BhojendraNepal The change uses the variable that contains the text. The current way is searching for `redundantText` in the text(), which doesn't exist.

Comment: the redundantText is considered as s string in previous..

Comment: You are replacing the text but doing nothing with the result

Comment: @atmd That is what the OP started with. I now have changed my answer

Comment: changed 'redundantText' to redundantText. Still does not work :(

Comment: none of the answers solved the problem yet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tried a different approach now:

```
var redundantText = "<span id=\"redundantText_wrapper\"> text text text <a href=\"#contact\">Contact Me</a> text text text</span>";

$('#collapse_1').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(".dropdown_collapse_1").addClass("dropdown-indicator");
  $(".dropdown_collapse_1").removeClass("dropdown-collapsed");
  $("#redundant_text_wrapper").after(redundantText);
});
$('#collapse_1').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(".dropdown_collapse_1").addClass("dropdown-collapsed");
  $(".dropdown_collapse_1").removeClass("dropdown-indicator");
   $('#redundantText_wrapper').remove();
});
```

So basically I use 'after' instead of 'append' and put the text into a span with ID. Now I can use $('#ID').remove(); to get rid of it on closing the tab.

Comment: this is ok, except you now temporarily have duplicate IDs in your html which is invalid

Comment: Hm, I don't see what ID would be duplicate. When I open the next Tab the oder one automatically closes. So that the hide.bs.collapse function triggers and deletes the #redundantText_wrapper from the other Tab.
And for all the other tabs there are IDs like #collapse_2, #collapse_3

Answer (score 3):

That should be:

```
$( "#redundant_text_wrapper").text( $( "#redundant_text_wrapper").text().replace('redundantText','') ) ;
```

Or if you want to replace all occurrences:

```
$( "#redundant_text_wrapper").text( $( "#redundant_text_wrapper").text().replace(/redundantText/g,'') ) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

`$( "#redundant_text_wrapper").text().replace('redundantText','')` just gets the text value, replaces it and does nothing with the result, so this line is ironically redundant.

Also as your `redundantText` contains html, you should probably be using `html()` instead of `text()`.

If you want to manipulate the existing html of an element, you should use the overload of [`html()` which takes a function](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) (there is also the [same available for text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)). This receives the current HTML of the element and returns the new HTML to set:

```
$( "#redundant_text_wrapper").html(function(index, oldHtml) {
    return oldHtml.replace(redundantText,'');
});
```

---

Saying all that, replacing the whole contents of the wrapper is less efficient and can break things like existing event handlers on elements inside it. I would say it is preferable to put your redundant text into another element, such as a `<span>`, and add and remove that instead (or just show and hide it):

```
// wrap it all in a <span> - give it a class to be sure
var redundantText = '<span class="redundant">text text text <a href=\"#contact\">Contact Me</a> text text text</span>';

$('#collapse_1').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(".dropdown_collapse_1").addClass("dropdown-indicator");
  $(".dropdown_collapse_1").removeClass("dropdown-collapsed");
  $("#redundant_text_wrapper").append(redundantText);
});

$('#collapse_1').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(".dropdown_collapse_1").addClass("dropdown-collapsed");
  $(".dropdown_collapse_1").removeClass("dropdown-indicator");
  // just find the span and remove it
  $("#redundant_text_wrapper > span.redundant").remove();
});
```

Comment: You are right, although it was just a typo in my post. I had no quotes around the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$( "#redundant_text_wrapper").text().replace('redundantText','');
```

To:

```
$( "#redundant_text_wrapper").text().replace(redundantText,'');
```

Remove the quotes around the variable. That way it will be seen as a variable and not as a string.

Or

```
$("#redundant_text_wrapper").text($("#redundant_text_wrapper").text().replace(redundantText,''));
```

This way it will first get the text than replace it and set it.

Comment: that was a mistake in my post, I had that. Does not work anyway :(

Comment: Have you also tried it with `html()` instead of `text()`. As `html()` will also get the html tags of the `a href`